# Change the color of an specific point in plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am trying to change the color of a specific point in a line graph in plotly. 
I found out that you can change the color of a trace with this code snippet:

```
var update = {
marker: {
    color: 'orange',
    size: 10
    }
};

Plotly.restyle('myDiv', update);
```

I also found out that it is possible to change the color of the first Point with:

```
Plotly.restyle('myDiv', 'marker.color', [['red']]);
```

But I don't understand how I am able to change the color of a specific point if I only know his x,y coordinates.

[Link](http://codepen.io/plotly/pen/xwmJvL) to a Codepen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For changing color of only a particular point (or a set of specific points), you can add them as individual traces, and setting the `mode` to `markers`. With reference to your codepen link:

```
var X = [1, 3];
var Y = [4, 3];

Plotly.addTraces(graphDiv,{
    x: X,
    y: Y,
    type: 'scatter',
    mode: 'markers',
    marker: {'color': 'black'},
    name: 'marker_trace'
  });
```

This will paint all the `(X,Y)` Pairs as black.

Hope it helps.. :)